# Как сделать анимацию вращение по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: android, анимация, android-animation, android-canvas, android-customview

Я создал `custom view` и нарисовал колесо фортуны в `onDraw()`.
Все отображается правильно, как я хотел.
Есть кнопка по нажатии которого колесо должен вращаться на определенный градус вокруг своей оси.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать эту анимацию?

Comment: Расширьте вопрос - предоставьте варианты которые вы уже пробовали и вам не помогли, ну а так `view.animate().rotation(float)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете XML файл в папке **res/anim**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Далее в коде:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //some code

    final Animation animationRotateCenter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            this, R.anim.rotate_center);

    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            yourView.startAnimation(animationRotateCenter);
        }
    });
}
```

А вообще анимировать что-либо можно по разному. Вот несколько статей на эту тему:

- [Introduction to animations - документация](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview)
- [Move a View with Animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view)
- [Анимации в Android по полочкам](https://habr.com/ru/post/347918/)
- [Создаем анимацию "Восход солнца"](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sunrise.php)
- [Animation with MotionLayout](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#0)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я уже пробовал это. Никак не реагирует((

Comment: Ну без вашего кода тут вам вряд-ли кто-то сможет помочь. Скорее всего тут проблема в реализации вашей кастомной View. И шаманить нужно что-то там.

Comment: Понял в чем дело...) Оказывается я вызывал init() в конструкторе с AttributeSet и defStyleAttr. Спасибо

Comment: столкнулся с еще одной проблемой... как остановить view в положении после анимации?  а то я ставлю на 270 градусов... и после истечение duratuin , view возвращается в исходную... заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну точно не скажу. View должна остаться в том положении куда вы ее переместили. Возможно у вас где-то вызывается после этого метод invalidate или другие методы ЖЦ View внутри самой VIew и она себя перерисовывает на прежнем месте

Comment: хмм, незнаю.. метод invalidate нет, попробовал RotateAnimation, у него тот же результат, после нашел anim.setFillAfter(true), и вроде работает... спасибо!